# Is there any limit on file count while we're splitting backup to multiple files?

Tags: sql-server-2016, backup

I'm trying to split the backup file into multiple files to copy them from one DC to another. Can't find any information about max file count. How many files I can create while I'm trying to split the backup file into multiple files?

Only information which I've found for now, is Ola's backup script, where he mentioned about 64 files:
https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to split the backup file?...by adjusting that parameter of Ola's script for future runs?

Comment: No, I wanted to use the native backup solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The allowed maximum of backup stripes is 64.

I couldn't find where this is documented in the [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/welcome-sql-server), but the answer can be found in `sys.messages` by looking at Error Message 3205.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.messages m
WHERE m.message_id = 3205
AND m.language_id = 1033; --Or your favorite language
```

> Too many backup devices specified for backup or restore; only %d are allowed.

Wait, no! That isn't helpful at all! `%d` is a substitution string, it doesn't give me the answer.

### Let's just brute force this.

Since you point out Ola's code references 64 as being too many, we can try backing up to 65 backup devices & see what happens.

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE msdb
TO  
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',    DISK = 'NUL',
    DISK = 'NUL' --65!
```

```
Msg 3205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Too many backup devices specified for backup or restore; only 64 are allowed.
```

I've checked this on both Express Edition & Enterprise Edition -- both give the same answer: **64.**

The error message appears to be built in a way that this number can be changed without changing the error message in `sys.messages`, but the number doesn't appear to be variable based on edition--at least not for the "box" product. Perhaps a cloud edition or in the future version this might change.